# Difference Between Axis 2 and Axis 2 Client in WSo2 Esb Property

Tags: wso2-api-manager, esb, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm new to WSO2 ESB. I cant seem to find the difference between axis2 and axis2-client scope of the property mediator.

Difference between

```
<property name="xyz" value="something" scope="axi2">  and

<property name="xyz" value="something" scope="axi2-client">
```

Comment: Hi Rishikesh, as you are new I would say, don't bother with the axis2 scopes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269918/what-exactly-is-the-transport-scope-in-property-mediators-in-wso2-esb for an explanation

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 different types of scopes for the [Property Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI640/Property+Mediator), namely

- Synapse (Default)
- axis2
- axis2-client
- Transport
- Operation

To understand the difference between Axis2 and Axis2-client you have to know about the Synapse scope first

Properties set in **Synapse** scope last as long as the request-response transaction exists.

**Axis2** scope has a much shorter lifespan compared to Synapse and is mostly used to pass parameters to the Axis2 Engine

[**Axis2-client**](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Accessing+Properties+with+XPath#AccessingPropertieswithXPath-axis2-client) is similar to Synapse. The difference is that axis2-client scope can be accessed inside the mediate() method of a custom mediator. This custom mediator however needs to be configured using a Class Mediator

Comment: So does that mean normally i cannot use a  property with a synapse scope within a custom mediator?